# Not showing dropdown menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the nested button group and dropdown menu and followed the tutorial of W3schools. And the dropdown menus are not displayed, here in the code Nirvana and pearl jam.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">POP</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Rock</button>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Grunge <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Nirvana</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pearl Jam</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us the link from where you are reading

Comment: Create a stackoverflow code snippet replicating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**    please include these all

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like u have not included "bootstrap.js" in your html file.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>

    </title>

    <style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Pop</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Pop 1</a>
        <a href="#">Pop 2</a>
        <a href="#">Pop 3</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Rock</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Rock 1</a>
        <a href="#">Rock 2</a>
        <a href="#">Rock 3</a>
       </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

This code makes it without bootstrap but your class names are bootstrap classes so you can use my code without bootstrap or you can include bootstrap to your code. Both of them will work.